# SyntaxForm not correctly parsed by FrontEnd

Tags: front-end, notebooks, syntax

When using `TagBox` with `SyntaxForm`, I noticed sometimes it is not well parsed by the `FrontEnd`. Here is a minimal example. First input

```
TagBox["f", "test", SyntaxForm -> "^"] // DisplayForm
```

Then copy the output `f` to new input, and do some prefix or postfix operations. There is an error message.

A screenshot is attached.

[image]

To debug further, one note that where there is a problem, in the saved file the cell is broken into more than one `RowBox`, for example:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  TagBox[
   TagBox["f",
    "test",
    SyntaxForm->"^"],
   DisplayForm], 
  RowBox[{"//", "ToBoxes", " ", 
   RowBox[{"(*", " ", 
    RowBox[{
    "this", " ", "f", " ", "is", " ", "copied", " ", "and", " ", "pasted", 
     " ", "from", " ", "the", " ", "above", " ", "line"}], " ", 
    "*)"}]}]}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.618418507443947*^9, 3.618418516513115*^9}},
 EmphasizeSyntaxErrors->True]
```

I am using Mathematica 10.0 on Linux x64. I have also tried `SyntaxForm->"a^b"`, or other operators. None of them work well.

Am I doing anything wrong or is it a bug?

**Edit:**

As @WReach commented, I should have provided more details about my goal, otherwise why not go without SyntaxForm? And here is what I wanted (still a simplified version of the realistic case): typeset derivative in a good-looking way.

The simplest implementation is

```
MakeBoxes[d[f_], StandardForm] := 
 TagBox[GridBox[{{"\[PartialD]", ToBoxes[f]}}], "d"]
```

However, if I evaluate

```
d[f]^2
```

> ∂ f²

This is not what I want (it evaluates correctly but does not look correct). Instead I want `(∂ f)²`. Note that here I could use `RowBox` instead of `GridBox` and then there is no such problem. But I do need `GridBox` in the realistic case because it is more feature-rich (I could use `RowBox[{GridBox[...], ""}]` to replace `GridBox[...]` as a workaround. But I hope there is a cleaner and less hacky way). Also the `Notation` package is not powerful enough for my actual need so I want to do it myself.

I think the logical move to solve this problem is to use `SyntaxForm`. Indeed, if I define

```
MakeBoxes[d2[f_], StandardForm] := 
 TagBox[GridBox[{{"\[PartialD]", ToBoxes[f]}}], "d2", SyntaxForm -> "^"]

MakeExpression[TagBox[GridBox[{{"\[PartialD]", f_}}], "d2", ___], 
  StandardForm] := With[{g = ToExpression@f}, HoldComplete@d2@g]
```

I get the desired `(∂ f)²` appearance for `d2[f]^2`. However, now the problem that I have described appears. If I evaluate `d2[f]`, and copy the output to new input and use, say, post-fix form of operators, it ends up with an error.

Comment: Still there in v10.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) instead of a [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox) should fix your problem.

```
MakeBoxes[d[f_], StandardForm] ^:= TemplateBox[
    {MakeBoxes[f]},
    "d",
    DisplayFunction->(GridBox[{{"\[PartialD]",#}}]&),
    SyntaxForm->"^"
]
```

Then:

```
d[f]^2
```

> [image]

And copying:

[image]

> Power[d[f],2]